# How to load object data saved in Unity C#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a universal storage system in Unity C#.
What my code not work? Object can't define or did I write wrong?

If not use functions from SaveExtensions then everything will work.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hLFRB2rHj7XcJT6et7TskEa7sLwdmJhP

Comment: In case anyone wonders about the rollback: [copying code from external sources isn't allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/6296561), unless OP does it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your saving works the problem is in your `Load` method.

```c#
obj = bf.Deserialize(fs);
```

this change is only applied locally inside the method but it doesn't actually change the value of the calling `ex` in

```c#
ex.Load("asd", ".dat", SaveExtension.Path.PersistentDataPath);
```

---

Unfortuanetly `ref` and `out` are not allowed in extension methods so one workaround might be giving the method a proper return value instead (I also made some changes to the rest of your code):

```c#
[System.Serializable]
internal static class SaveExtension
{
    public enum Path 
    { 
        PersistentDataPath, 
        TemporaryCachePath 
    }

    public static void Save(this object obj, string name, string type, Path path)
    {
        var pathString = "";

        switch (path)
        {
            case Path.PersistentDataPath:
                pathString = Application.persistentDataPath;
                break;
            case Path.TemporaryCachePath:
                pathString = Application.temporaryCachePath;
                break;
        }

        // There is no need to create the file 
        // in a dedicated if block since it will be created anyway
        // Additionally: You did only create a new file but due to
        // if-else you didn't write to it the first time

        Debug.Log("[SaveSystem]: File " + name + type + " already exist!");
        Debug.Log("[SaveSystem]: Location: " + pathString + "/" + name + type);

        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var fs = File.Open(pathString + "/" + name + type, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            bf.Serialize(fs, obj);
        }

        Debug.Log("[SaveSystem]: Object succesful serialized!");
    }

    public static T Load<T>(this T obj, string name, string type, Path path)
    {
        var output = default(T);

        var pathString = "";

        switch (path)
        {
            case Path.PersistentDataPath:
                pathString = Application.persistentDataPath;
                break;
            case Path.TemporaryCachePath:
                pathString = Application.temporaryCachePath;
                break;
        }

        if (!File.Exists(pathString + "/" + name + type))
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("File " + pathString + "/" + name + type + " not found! returning default value.");
            return output;
        }

        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var fs = File.Open(pathString + "/" + name + type, FileMode.Open))
        {
            output = (T)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        }

        Debug.Log("[SaveSystem]: Object succesful deserialized!");

        return output;
    }
}
```

and use it like

```c#
ex = ex.Load("asd", ".dat", SaveExtension.Path.PersistentDataPath);
```

This way the `this T obj` is only used to define the type `T`

---

Just a hint: You should never use `Debug.Log` inside of `Update` ... for debugging simply switch the [Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html) in Unity to the [`Debug` mode](http://unitylore.com/articles/unity-debug-inspector/) than you can directly see private fields.